# Eclipse EE - Java EE perspective Vs Java perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

If one is using Eclipse EE is there any reason to use the Java Perspective over the Java EE Perspective ?
In other words for Eclipse EE is the Java Perspective essentially redundant (a subset of the Java EE one) and not to be used or is it the case they are identical functionally ?

When working in Eclipse I had historically mainly used the Java Perspective and when I installed Java EE eclipse none of the working sets (available in the Java Perspective) were visible in the Java EE perspective, so I'm wondering if I can just dispense with ever using Java Perspective going forward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think only the default setting maybe different from Java perspective. But you can add new items.

> The Java™ EE perspective includes workbench views that you can use
>   when developing resources for enterprise applications, EJB modules,
>   Web modules, application client modules, and connector projects or
>   modules.

-> http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcjpers.html

Comment: Thanks Master yes I think I'll bite the bullet and set up the working sets in the Java EE Perspective and ignore the Java Perspective from here on.